# Как защитить CSV или JSON базу данных в мобильном приложении?

Tags: json, csv, мобильная-разработка

Сейчас пишу мобильное приложение, для его работы необходима база данных (собираю вручную, очень долго, поэтому не хочется чтобы какой нибудь Вася Пупкин однажды заглянул в apk и все мои труды забрал например к себе в проект).
У меня было 2 варианта:

1. Шифрование (Но как я понял бесплатные варианты так себе шифруют и могут быть в лёгкую расшифрованы)
2. Хранить на сервере (Но в этом случае нужен мощный сервер который выдержит нагрузку)

Что думаете? Может быть есть вариант №3? или же я где то не прав в вариантах 1 и 2, поправьте меня. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы не правы с самого начала, не желая делиться с другими, тогда как сами пользуетесь кучей абсолютно бесплатного софта, может даже не догадываясь об этом

Comment: У меня есть прямой конкурент который может и "подрезать" себе всю мою базу. И он с этого выигрывает больше чем я. Ведь у него уже есть аудитория, а у меня нет